# .img-responsive breaks when used with .pull-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got some images that have `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` to align them in a specific pattern. I'm also using `.img-responsive`.

The images look like this:

```
<img src="~/Images/test-modern.jpg" class="pull-right img-responsive" />
<img src="~/Images/test-modern.jpg" class="pull-left img-responsive" />
```

It seems that for the images that have `.pull-right .img-responsive` does not work. However, it does work with `.pull-left`.

`.pull-right` uses `float:right` in the background and if I find that in the F12 tools and toggle it on and off I can see `.img-responsive` also turning on and off.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `.img-responsive` set `max-width: 100%`. It works only when you've got a single element per line. Here are two options to change this, choose the one which fit you need.

### Option #1 : pictures stick the sides

```
<div class="row-pictures">
    <img src="~/Images/test-modern.jpg" class="pull-right img-responsive">
    <img src="~/Images/test-modern.jpg" class="pul-left img-responsive">
</div>
```

```
.row-pictures .img-responsive {
  max-width: 50%
}
```

**[Bootply example](http://bootply.com/97470)**

This will make pictures to stick both sides.

### Option #2 : pictures stick each other

```
<div class="row row-pictures">
    <img src="~/Images/test-modern.jpg" class="col-xs-6 img-responsive" />
    <img src="~/Images/test-modern.jpg" class="col-xs-6 img-responsive" />
</div>
```

```
.row-pictures img {
    padding: 0; /* optional: only to remove the gutter */
}
```

**[Bootply example](http://bootply.com/97471)**

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `pull-left` and `pull-right` use `col-**` classes for that.