# what is wrong with the img-responsive?

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm currently following a tutorial on bootstrap, but seem to be misunderstanding something.

I want to make mye images responsive, and the tut claims that that is done bye adding the img-responsive class to the img tag like this:

```
<p><img src="img/cockatiel.jpg" class="pull-right img-responsive">
```

I've done this with all the imgages on the site...

What am I doing wrong

Comment: You'll definitely need to post some of your markup here to get responses.

Answer (score 1):

Do a simple search on Google as I just did. My Search parameter:
class="pull-right img-responsive"
My result:
[.img-responsive breaks when used with .pull-right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260045/img-responsive-breaks-when-used-with-pull-right)